# Center aligned grid with content left justifies

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, slds-grid

I have a grid where we have 4 columns like below:

[image]

The problem is that I wan't the 4th column to start from absolute left of the center aligned grid. How can I achieve this?

Below is the code:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-guttters slds-grid_align-center">
    <template for:each={resources} for:item="item">
        <div key={item.Id} class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-3 slds-medium-size_2-of-3 slds-small-size_1-of-1 slds-var-m-around_medium">
            CONTENT HERE...  
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

I also tried wrapping  inside another container div for center alignment but that disturbs the flex alignment and moves all the columns in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is `slds-grid_align-center` class which is incorrectly applied to the grid div. This class basically centres all its children in absolute terms.

We can fix this by wrapping the grid in a outer container div and horizontally aligning it with flex box layout as shown below :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-guttters">
      <template for:each={resources} for:item="item">
          <div key={item.Id} class="slds-col slds-large-size_1-of-3 slds-medium-size_2-of-3 slds-small-size_1-of-1 slds-var-m-around_medium">
              CONTENT HERE...
          </div>
      </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

css class for container:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Here's the output :
[image]

Comment: @sfdcnoob : Removed border from the code.

Comment: this breaks the grid layout as it now displays only 2 columns instead of 3.

Comment: That's because you want to centre align the grid. Due to centre alignment , available width will decrease.
You can then adjust the width of individual columns for having 3 columns.

Comment: @sfdcnoob If it helps you , please mark this as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to go with SLDS classes, you can make use of below plain CSS styling:

```
<div style="display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;">
    <template for:each={resources} for:item="item">
        <div key={item.Id} style="width: 33.33%;">
            Content
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```